# Sort array items in PHP so that it is not case sensitive to letters

Tags: php, sorting, case-sensitive

When I use `sort($topics)` I get something along the lines of:

1. Apple
2. Green
3. Zebra
4. grass

In this example, "grass" starts with a lower case g but ends up after "Zebra" which has a capital letter.

How do I make it so that it sorts it where it ignores whether the word starts with capitals or not?

1. Apple
2. Green
3. grass
4. Zebra

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Call [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) as `usort($topics, 'strnatcasecmp')`.

`strcasecmp` would do the job, too, but [`strnatcasecmp`](http://php.net/strnatcasecmp) will also sort properly when you have numbers in your string.

Answer (score 25):

There is  [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) .

```
natcasesort($topics);
```

Comment: note: natcasesort sorts special characters (dots, underscores...) differently