# How would I sort names (first and last name) alphabetically in PHP, case insensitive?

Tags: php, sorting, alphabetical

I am trying to sort an array of student names alphabetically. In the array we have $user['firstname'] and $user['lastname']. I want to sort it such that A/a comes first and then Z/z comes last. If their first names are the same then we compare with last name. My problem is that I've already created the functionality for this sorting but it is not case insensitive.

This is what I've done so far:

```
uasort($students, array($this, 'nameCompare'));
private function nameCompare($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['firstname'] == $b['firstname']) 
    {
        if($a['lastname'] < $b['lastname'])
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if ($a['lastname'] > $b['lastname'])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else //last name and first name are the same
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return ($a['firstname'] < $b['firstname']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [`strnatcasecmp()`](http://php.net/strnatcasecmp) in place of the greater and less than operators.

Comment: If you want case-insensitive, then force your values to be all lowercase (or all uppercase) before doing the actual comparisons... and when working with string compares, look at the strcmp() function - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php - rather than > and <

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort array items in PHP so that it is not case sensitive to letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763936/sort-array-items-in-php-so-that-it-is-not-case-sensitive-to-letters)

Comment: Cheers mario, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think the [strtolower](http://www.php.net/strtolower) function could be useful. At the beginning of your function just add this:

```
$a['firstname'] = strtolower($a['firstname']);
$a['lastname'] = strtolower($a['lastname']);
$b['firstname'] = strtolower($b['firstname']);
$b['lastname'] = strtolower($b['lastname']);
```

By doing this you convert all values to lower case, removing the "sensitiveness" of the function.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
usort($students, function($a, $b) {
  if($cmp = strnatcasecmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname'])) return $cmp;
  return strnatcasecmp($a['firstname'], $b['firstname']);
});
```